# WPF DataTrigger Binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a search box which i am trying to to check if it is empty by using the "hasdata" and if empty return false else return true, but the DataTrigger Binding is not working. can someone point me in the right direction on what i am doing wrong.

code:

```
public bool hasdata
{
    get { if (searchBox.Text.Count() == 0) return false; else return true; }
}
```

xaml:

```
<telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox x:Name="searchBox"/>
<Image Source="SomeImage.png" >
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=hasdata}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=hasdata}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: for this particular case, you should just binding the `Visibility` to your `hasdata` and set the binding `Converter` to `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`

Comment: What are you doing wrong?  Practically everything, unfortunately.  Your biggest problem is that you don't understand how databinding works.  I'd strongly suggest you stop what you're doing and go search for "how does databinding work in WPF" here and on MSDN.  You'll find many top links that describe the process.

Comment: @Bolu: That will, at most, be evaluated once.

Comment: @Will 100% yes, by that comment, I'm not suggesting that is a answer. just a side note.

Comment: just get rid of the has data property all together. Don't rly need it from what we see of your code. First set a Style Default Setter for Visibility as `Visible`. Next you only need one `Trigger`. Use a `ElementName=searchBox, Path=Text` binding and check if `Value={x:Static sys:String.Empty}` and switch the Visibility to `Hidden`. DP or INPC for a property that isnt even needed is just overkill. Oh and do follow @Will 's suggestion to read up on some basics

Answer (score 4):

The UI has currently no way of being notified when `hasdata` is changed. You need to either implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface or make `hasdata` a `DependencyProperty`.